# Differentiate target consumer in MassTransit

Tags: apache-kafka, masstransit

There are few consumers listening on one Kafka topic. A message has a parameter by which it can be determined which consumer needs to consume it. What mechanism of MassTransit use to implement such a solution?

Answer (score 1):

As [explained in the interoperability documentation](https://masstransit-project.com/architecture/interoperability.html), MassTransit uses the `messageType` header to determine which message types are present in the serialized message body. If there are no message types, such as when the RawJson message deserializer is used, it will deliver the message to all registered consumers.

Now, with Kafka, the type itself is part of the `TopicEndpoint` configuration, so only that message type is dispatched to the endpoint. Depending upon the serialization (AVRO, Json, etc.) the experience depends upon whether or not the message types are available.

You could certainly write your own deserializer that uses that parameter to determine which message types are in the message and write your own deserializer to properly respond to `TryGetMessage<T>` with the supported types. The best example of that would be either the `JsonConsumeContext`, or the recently updated `RawJsonConsumeContext` that now supports transport headers for message identification.